# PHP MySQL database insert issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am building a MySQL database using PHP to bring in JSON data from the NYTimes API.  I have it all built and have included the script below but for some reason when I go to insert the records into the database, it doesn't seem to complete the insert function all the way through or actually insert the records into the database and I am really confused why.  Any insight as to why this is happening or how to adjust it would be greatly appreciated.

MakeDatabase.php-

```
<?php

function PullData($url,$adx_keywords,$title,$abstract)
{
    $json = file_get_contents("http://api.nytimes.com/svc/mostpopular/v2/mostviewed/arts,sports/30.json?api-key=1a8bc0eb977b14db91dea9318942608b%3A14%3A72549166");
    $json_decoded=  json_decode($json,true);

    foreach ($json_decoded['results'] as $articles){
        array_push($url,$articles['url']);
        array_push($adx_keywords,$articles['adx_keywords']);
        array_push($title,$articles['title']);
        array_push($abstract,$articles['abstract']);
    }

}

function MakeDatabase($conn,$db_NAME)
{


// Create database
        $sql_createDB = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " . $db_NAME;

        if ($conn->query($sql_createDB) === TRUE) {
             echo "Database linked successfully <br>";
      } else {
        echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
}
}

function createTable($tablename, $db_NAME, $conn, $fields)
{
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_NAME);

        $sql_create = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tablename (
                id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                $fields[0] TEXT,
                $fields[1] TEXT,
                $fields[2] TEXT,
                $fields[3] TEXT
                )";    

        if ($conn->query($sql_create) === TRUE) {
            echo "Table Articles created successfully <br>";
        } else {
            echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error . "<br>";
        }

}

function insertRecords($array,$fieldname, $conn, $db_NAME)
{
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_NAME);
    foreach ($array as $records)
    {
        $sql_insert="INSERT INTO tbl_articles('$fieldname')"
                . "VALUES('$records')";

        echo $sql_insert . "<br>";

        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql_insert))
        {
            echo "Records Inserted.";
        }
        else 
        {
            die('Error : ' . mysqli_error($conn) . "<br>");
        }
    }
}




?>
```

index.php-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        require 'MakeDatabase.php';

        $db_NAME="nytimesnews";
        $tblName="tbl_articles";
        $fields=array('url','adx_keywords','title','abstract');

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";

        $url=array();
        $adx_keywords=array();
        $title=array();
        $abstract=array();

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

        MakeDatabase($conn,$db_NAME);
        PullData($url,$adx_keywords,$title,$abstract);
        createTable($tblName, $db_NAME, $conn, $fields);
        insertRecords($url, 'url', $conn, $db_NAME);
        insertRecords($adx_keywords, 'keywords', $conn, $db_NAME);


        $conn->close();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors being displayed? Is error reporting on?

Comment: We (and you) need to see the error output.

Comment: No, no errors are being displayed.  As you can see from the insert function, there is supposed to be a sql statement being echoed onto the screen but that isn't even happening.

Comment: Does the database and table exist (implying that your script successfully created them in a previous iteration)?

Comment: Yes they both exist. The script does everything but insert records.

Comment: @Thomas this is your insert query copied from your code. `$sql_insert="INSERT INTO tbl_articles('$fieldname')" . "VALUES('$records')";` notice anything wrong?

Comment: As @Script47 just pointed out, you are not inserting properly.

Comment: Yeah post it...still not 100% clear to me...I suspect that he is not expanding out the terms to `INSERT` but is instead _iterating_ over the terms one by one.

Comment: this `die('Error : ' . mysqli_error($conn) . "<br>");` should be throwing you syntax errors here, but you haven't shared that with us.

Comment: @Fred-ii- he might not have error reporting enabled? Or he doesn't know what error reporting is so this might be an issue, going to update my answer just in case.

Comment: @Script47 Error reporting would not signal syntax errors in a query, that is for PHP syntax errors, not MySQL. `mysqli_error` would.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this will fix the issue, however there is an error in your `insert` query.

Your query,

```
$sql_insert="INSERT INTO tbl_articles('$fieldname')" . "VALUES('$records')";
```

What it should be,

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO `tbl_articles` (`" . $fieldname . "`) VALUES ('" . $records . "')";
```

I reformatted it too to make it clearer.

Also, turn on `error reporting` if it is not on alreasdy to make debugging easier for you and us, that way you know what errors are being thrown and can either fix them or tell us so we know where abouts in the code it is going wrong.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Comment: *Hm....* this `('" . $fieldname . "')` that might be an issue. Columns shouldn't be using quotes `'` (usually values does), but using ticks. I don't know how to format ticks as code in here, but replacing `'` with `\`` for both may be what's needed here. *Just a thought* and making a sidenote in your answer under your original.